# Reading Microphone Data by Polling using ALSA [or V4L2]

Tags: linux, alsa, multimedia, v4l2

I am trying to read data from multiple microphones in Linux (ubuntu 14.04). I have a specific constraint that the reading from microphones should be via polling(so no waiting until there is data, although the data comes in high frequency). I wanted to know if that is possible in Linux? Unfortunately audio capture is not the area of my expertise and I would like to know if the choice of using Alsa is a good one. To better understand the problem, here is a pseudo-code that I had in mind:

```
open_the_audio_device();
set_the_parameters_of_the_audio_device();
while (!done)
{
    poll_result=poll_the_devices(); //other non-audio devices are also polled here preferably, something like using select on all different file descriptors of audio, video, socket, etc.      
    if(poll_success_for_audio_device)
          receive_audio_from_the_device_that_has_data();
    else
          do_some_other_very_fast_stuff_and_start_loop_again();
}
close_the_device();
```

My questions are 2 fold:

1. Is Alsa a good choice for this?
2. Can it be done somehow with some library that gives me a file descriptor so that I can use it with select function? if so this is optimal because there are other non-audio devices also working with select.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the `snd_pcm_read*()` calls from blocking, enable non-blocking mode with [snd_pcm_nonblock()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga8d9ed4a62c17402de0389fd31fc7dc1f).

To get pollable file descriptors, call [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_count()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gac7f4cdb1c930b8d343714f60afa02fc4) and [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga742e8705f6992fd0e36efc868e574f01).
It is possible to have multiple descriptors because some plugins might implement notifications differently.
To translate the result of a `poll()` on those descriptors back into a `POLLIN`/`POLLOUT` value, call [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_revents()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga7e561f305702c6f52dab49b6c84f7df7).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Is there an intuitive example of using these functions in a select or poll (functions) scenario? I read the description and I have a good idea of what I need to do. Just wanted to know if there is a full duplex example to make sure I am going in the right direction.

Comment: A full duplex user would be Jack, but it's not quite an intuitive example.

Comment: An example https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html