# How to fill ALSA buffer in timely manner

Tags: audio, synchronization, real-time, alsa

ALSA uses write function to fill circular buffer then sound card play the samples and drain the buffer. Application takes responsibility of refilling the buffer with next fragments of the stream. If app application fills buffer to slow there are gaps in the music. If application fills it to quick not yet played samples are overwritten by new ones because buffer is circular.

My question is how do I know when I should refill buffer and how much of it. Are there some events defined by alsa or are ther other techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the PCM device is in blocking mode (the default), `snd_pcm_write*()` will wait until all bytes have actually been written to the buffer. Unplayed samples never are overwritten.

When the PCM device is in non-blocking mode, `snd_pcm_write*()` will return how many frames have actually been written (or return -EAGAIN if the buffer is completely full). To wait for some space to become available, use `poll()`, which allows to use an event loop that waits for multiple types of events. (See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826255/11654) for details.)

Comment: Polling uses a lot o processor time. Does alsa have solution based on callbacks?

Comment: `poll()` is not polling.

Comment: Actually poll will poll when timeout 0 is given. It will block though when timeout greater than 0 is given.